# Setting Orderline Pricelevel to Custom using SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: suitescript2.0

I'm trying to set the amount of a discount using suitescript. I can add the discount line but I need to be able to set it to discount amount.

**Current Code**

```
salesOrder.setCurrentSublistText({   
    sublistId   : 'item',
    fieldId     : 'item',
    text        : ECOM_BUNDLE
});
salesOrder.setCurrentSublistText({   
    sublistId   : 'item',
    fieldId     : 'pricelevel',
    text        : 'Custom'
});
salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({   
    sublistId   : 'item',
    fieldId     : 'amount',
    value       : -100
});
salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId   : 'item',
    fieldId     : 'description',
    value       : orderLine.description 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution that I found. Change the 'pricelevel' fieldId to 'price'. Changed 'setCurrentSublistText' to 'setCurrentSublistValue'. Changed 'Custom' to -1. -1 is the internal id for custom pricelevel.

```
salesOrder.setCurrentSublistText({   
    sublistId   : 'item',
    fieldId     : 'item',
    text        : ECOM_BUNDLE
});
salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({   
    sublistId   : 'item',
    fieldId     : 'price',
    value       : -1
});
salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({   
    sublistId   : 'item',
    fieldId     : 'amount',
    value       : -100
});
salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId   : 'item',
    fieldId     : 'description',
    value       : orderLine.description 
});
```